# How do I decide where to put the file while creating it in python?

Tags: python

With the code `open`, I can create a new file in the computer. How do i decide which folder it goes? I need to put them in a certain folder when i am creating them. Should I put sth in the brackets?
e.g. `open("apple juice. txt", "a")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a path, then the file will be created in the current directory. Where exactly that is depends on how you started the interpreter. For example, when you start Python 3.4 from the Windows Start Menu, then the file will be saved in `C:\Python34\`.

If you want to specify a certain path, then do so:

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\David\Python Files\apple juice.txt", "a")
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the full path:

```
 with open("path_where/to_save/apple_juice.txt", "a") as f:
    # do work
```

[with](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) will automatically  close your file.

Comment: `with` is a better option as ... (Should have explained why...)

Comment: thank you, it is a quite an efficient solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a place for temp files, use the module [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile).

You can use the function [tempfile.gettempdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) to get a path to a folder  directory.

You can use [tempfile.TemporaryFile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) to generate a full path to the place where the temp files are usually stored on your OS.

The method used in either case to generate the temp path is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir).